# Discourage the use of "what's wrong with my code" as a title

Tags: discussion, questions, title

On StackOverflow, there are [hundreds of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what%27s+wrong+with+my+code) that are titled something like:

> *What's wrong with my code?*

Personally I don't think that's a good title: the majority of all questions deal with code with one or a few errors. The amount of questions that could use this title is endless. Furthermore the title does not provide any information. Given one is an expert in one domain, besides the tags (that are in many of such cases problematic as well), he/she has no clue whether he/she can answer the question.

I was wondering if it would be possible to discourage this behavior. For instance similar to people asking questions where the word *regex* appears in the titlebar get a popup that advices people to ask the question properly.

In short: should StackOverflow discourage the title "*what's wrong with my code?*"?

Comment: bad titles are already discouraged...

Comment: @JustDoIt: Well I did a short test, and nothing happened... I mean not using downvotes or close votes, but before the harm is done...

Comment: You're asking for something similar to the "problem" ban in titles... Which users just work around. ("pr0blem", "prblem", etc.)

Comment: @Kendra: not per se a ban. Indeed one will not filter out all instances, the point is however to reduce the amount of questions with such title.

Comment: There's a generic warning of "this post may be closed as opinion based", you want the same (a generic warning) without pointing out to the specific phrase, right?

Comment: @Braiam: indeed. Although the way how it is implemented is open for discussion. Whether it is a warning, a ban, a popup, etc. is more a matter of taste.

Comment: discourage the use of it entirely, not just in title.

Comment: [Random example of the day](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34657609/2564301) - no need for the Meta effect to step in, it got closed already.

Comment: There are only [172 with that phrase in the title](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22what%27s+wrong+with+my+code%22+is%3Aq)

Comment: You can always down vote the question for being unclear. Down votes are very discouraging. I like to just edit the question if it's salvageable.

Comment: I am also starting to get annoyed with titles like "HTML/CSS issue".

Comment: @TinyGiant: mind the *something like*, this generates some extras: [+143](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22what%27s+wrong+with+this+code%22+is%3Aq), [+52](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22whats+wrong+with+this+code%22+is%3Aq), [+68](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22whats+wrong+with+my+code%22+is%3Aq),... Indeed the problem can be solved by editing. I'm just thinking about the time tht is collectively wasted by people looking to questions that they cannot determine whether they have much expertise in it.

Comment: @torazaburo perhaps see the use in such poor titles; they're an excellent quality indicator of the question itself. If you're out to answer questions rather than moderate them, then you can instantly see which ones to skip. In that same line of thinking, I wouldn't focus on question titles myself as the thing to be discouraged. Its the poor and/or off-topic questions that need further discouraging, maybe.

Comment: Simple solution: make it easier to delete crap.

Comment: I love those titles. As such a title is not useful for searchers and almost all such questions are crap, I can quickly improve the quality of the site by downvoting them without detailed investigation.

Comment: Idea: based on poorness of the title (and other indicators), you could reduce the number of votes needed to close the question, and display that number (or a proxy for it) at submission time.